# How should I host abp.io Blazor project on heroku?

Tags: .net, heroku, blazor, abp

I am using abp.io + Blazor template, I want to host it using Heroku.

Is it possible to achieve this using one dyno? If so, should I (and how) run .Blazor and .HttpApi projects there?

Should they be split up into two dynos (one with .Blazor and second one with .HttpApi)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is it possible to achieve this using one dyno?

Yes it is, you can use this build pack : https://github.com/Aguafrommars/dotnetcore-buildpack. It's used to deploy https://theidserver.herokuapp.com/.

For net5.0 set up env vars :

- DOTNET_RUNTIME_VERSION=5.0.0
- DOTNET_SDK_VERSION=5.0.100

2. Should they be split up into two dynos?

Yes, you just need to deploy 2 projects. The env var PROJECT_FILE defined the path to the .csproj to build and deploy.

Comment: Thanks, I will create two dynos. I just thought that it should be all in one since I am using Blazor.